# Why i get a error - indexOf Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

What's the Problem?
Why it cannot find the function indexOf and length?

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    var string1 = document.location;
    var stringpos;
    stringpos = string1.indexOf('#');

    var hashstring = string1.substring(stringpos,string1.length());

    alert(hashstring);

    alert("location: " + document.location);
};
```

Comment: Because `document.location` is an object. Try `document.location.href`.

Answer (score 2):

`document.location` is an object which does not have the `indexOf` method. In general, only expect strings and arrays to have that method (and `document.location` is neither of those).

I think you wanted to use `indexOf` on `document.location.href`, which is a string:

```js
document.location.href.indexOf('#');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the hash directly instead of with string manipulation.

```
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        var hashstring = document.location.hash;
        alert(hashstring);
        alert("location: " + document.location);
    };
```

Comment: document.location is an object. i tried with Location.href now it works. thx a lot

Comment: No problem! If this answers the question you should up vote and mark correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use

```
var string1 = document.location.href
```

or

```
var string1 = document.location.toString()
```

then use `string1.length` instead of `string1.length()` which throws Uncaught TypeError: string1.length is not a function